# Need a (simple) SQLite Statement

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I have two Tables

```
FRIENDS 
id 
friendID 
name 
prename

FRIENDLIST 
id 
userID 
friendID
```

I pass a UserID( called myPassedUserID)

I need a SQLite select query. It should lookup all friendIDs in FRIENDLIST where userID=myPassedUserID and then retreive all Columms from FRIENDS that match the friendIDs i just looked up.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT *

FROM FRIENDS
WHERE friendID IN 
(
    SELECT friendID  
    FROM FRIENDLIST 
    WHERE userID=myPassedUserID
)
```

but I read that it isn't good for performance reasons.

Comment: What have you tried? SO isn't a place where we just give you free code; it's a place where we help you solve problems.

Comment: As written your question reads like you expect us to do your thinking for you.  Show us the code you've written to try to solve this and why you think it's wrong.  You should also read [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) - it's very useful.

Comment: I suspect the performance comment is referring to correlated subqueries which can give horrible query plans. This query is not correlated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT FRIENDS.* from FRIENDS
INNER JOIN FRIENDLIST
ON FRIENDS.FriendID = FRIENDLIST.FriendID
WHERE FRIENDLIST.userID = ?
```